# How to allocate memory and dereference an array of arrays within a struct?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I was wondering how I would access a double pointer inside of a struct, for example:

```
typedef struct Example {
   char **set;
   int size;
 }Example;
```

The struct is called inside the function as:

```
struct Example exmpl;
```

If I needed to create a new array within that array of arrays, how would I call it in a function/main?
Or is it just the same as regular, `exmpl->set`?

Comment: Yes, I need to allocate it too!

Comment: There is no "array of arrays" in your struct! A pointer is not an array (or vice-versa).

Comment: Try posting code that does this for a `char *set;` member first and then ask about `char **set;`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what the type of `set` is, you access it with `exmpl.set`. If you need to access a single element it would be `exmpl.set[0][0]` for example.

If you need to allocate memory for it, you need to allocate memory for the outer array and then for each inner array independently, like this to create an array of 10x20:

```
struct Example exmpl;
exmpl.set = malloc(10 * sizeof(char*));       // 10 "arrays" in the set
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    exmpl.set[i] = malloc(20 * sizeof(char)); // 20 chars within each "array"
```

Then for setting each element's value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        exmpl.set[i][j] = calculate(i, j);
```

And, an array and a pointer are different, so what you have here is a pointer to a pointer to char (which works similarly to a 2-dimensional array of chars)

Comment: [Concerning casting the result of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2410359)

Comment: Don't forget to set `exmpl.size = 10;` too.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Would I still need to use the for loop even if its an array of strings?

Comment: **For creation:** it depends on how you construct your strings, remember they need to live somewhere in memory, how are you constructing them?
**For setting each element's value:** you'll still need the outer-most loop, but not the inner-most one because you can use things like `strcpy` which do the char-by-char copy for you (or you can just copy the pointer if the strings live somewhere else in memory).